# Entity framework 6.0 : How can i ensure transactional integrity between two entities where one need assigned Id of the other entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactionscope

I have seen numerous questions and advice on calling dbContext.SaveChanges multiple Times in a transaction.
Some say this should be avoided. This in depth post is really worth a read http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/

In my particular scenario  entity B has Id reference to Entity A

During a creation scenario i Create A and call savechanges in order to get A.Id assigned by database.
Then I create Entity B like new B(A.Id,....)
and call savechanges again. It could look like this in pseudo code

```
using(var tx =  dbContext.BeginTransaction())
{
    var a = new A();
    dbContext.Add(a);  //a.Id is null
    dbContext.saveChanges(); // a.Id has now been initialized

    var b = new B(a.Id); //I want to create b in a valid state so a.Id  cannot be null
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
    tx.Commit();
}
```

(I know the pseudo code lacks exception handling logic...)

Why is this a problem ?
Is it because the savechanges cannot be rolled back?

I know I could remodel but that is not possible because we share database with some legacy systems, so the database cannot easily be changed, if possible at all!

What is an alternative solution ?

Comment: What is the question, given that Entity Framework does support explicit transactions? You seem to write Pseudocode for a feature that you seem to miss while your pseudocode actually calls a method that exists. Did you bother the documentation? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx titled "Working with Transactions (EF6 Onwards)".

Comment: SaveChanges uses an internal transaction. Changing assignments is *already* atomic. What is the actual question? Just because someone wrote somewhere that you should call `SaveChanges` multiple times doesn't mean it's right. In fact, why does *your code* call it twice??.

Comment: There's no reason to assign IDs if you use proper relations. EF will recognize the new/modified classes and generate SQL statements that will insert the new objects in the proper order

Comment: Thx for the comments. Yes I have read the article working with transactions. In some cases I might prefer only refererencing by Id and not having an object relation. My code calls SaveChanges first  time in order to  get the Id of A so that I can initialize B. I HAve two questions: 1) Its not clear to me why calling savechages two times is  bad. 2) Alternative ways to solve the problem. I Appreciate the suggestions you have given..

Answer (score 2):

Use a [navigation property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738520%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) like this:

```
public class A
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int BId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("BId")]
    public B B { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

then simply assign the newly created `B` to `A`'s navigation property:

```
using (var transaction = dbContext.BeginTransaction())
{
    var a = new A();
    a.B = new B();
    dbContext.Add(a);
    dbContext.saveChanges();
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Comment: SaveChanges already uses a transaction. Other than that, the use of a navigation property is the correct way to handle relations

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: correct - just wanted to keep the code similar to the OPs "pseudo code" :)